# How to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n(1/2)^{2n+2}(n+2)/(2n+2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial, catalan-numbers

This is a follow-up to [a previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987203/how-to-calculate-sum-n-0-inftyc-n-left-frac12-right2n1-left-fr), which was answered as follows:
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\!2n+1}\!\!\left(\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4},$$
where $C_n$ is the $n$th Catalan number.

A related problem has arisen which asks for the following summation:
$$T=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\!2n+2}\!\!\left(\frac{n+2}{2n+2}\right),$$
where $A_n$ is [integer sequence A000245](https://oeis.org/A000245) (a "Catalan sequence convolved with its shifted variant") given by:
$$A_n=3\frac{(2n)!}{(n+2)!\cdot(n-1)!}.$$
Any thoughts on how to proceed? I am wondering if $S<T$.

Comment: It's a hypergeometric series, consider the ratio of consecutive terms and bring it to the form given in this Wikipedia article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$ we have $\frac{A_n}{4^n}\sim\frac{D}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $T$ *is not* a convergent series.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: There is obviously a misprint in the denominator of $A_n$: it should be $(n+2)!$ instead of $(n+1)!$ (cf. definition of A000245). Then the series converges.

Comment: oops. corrected! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that $A_n$ is defined as $\frac{3(2n)!}{(n+\color{red}{2})!(n-1)!}$ (otherwise the associated series is divergent, since $\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$) we have that $T$ equals

$$ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{8}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{n}{(n+1)^2} $$
which due to $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ can be written as
$$ T = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{8}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}-1\right)(1+\log x)\,dx = \color{red}{-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{2}\log 2}.$$

Comment: Please, explain the last line (starting with "can be written as") in more detail.

Comment: @user: $$\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\int_{0}^{1}x^n(1+\log x)\,dx.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I see. It would look probably even nicer if one let the sum start with  $n=0$ to obtain $$T=\frac1{2}+\frac3{8}\int_0^1\frac {1+\log x}{\sqrt {1-x}}dx. $$